# Binary search tree delete node function

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree, treenode

My delete function doesn't work when I try to delete node with only right child. It works when node has left child only or has both left and right.

I would like to know if this is a valid approach to this problem. I know how to write this in C++ but I need it to work in C# also.

```
//Private method, with args: root node, node to be deleted
private Node DeleteN(Node root, Node deleteNode) 
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return root;
    }
    if (deleteNode.data < root.data)
    {
        root.left = DeleteN(root.left, deleteNode);
    }
    if (deleteNode.data > root.data)
    {
        root.right = DeleteN(root.right, deleteNode);
    }
    if (deleteNode.data == root.data)
    {
        //No child nodes
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
        {
            root = null;
            return root;
        }
        //No left child - DONT WORK
        else if (root.left == null)
        {
            Node temp = root;
            root = root.right;
            temp = null;
        }
        //No right child
        else if (root.right == null)
        {
            Node temp = root;
            root = root.left;
            temp = null;
        }
        //Has both child nodes
        else
        {
            Node min = FindMin2(root.right);
            root.data = min.data;
            root.right =  DeleteN(root.right, min);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

//Public method with arg: int value of node to be deleted
public void DeleteNode(int x)
{
    Node deleteNode = new Node(x);
    DeleteN(root, deleteNode);
}
```

Comment: In `DeleteNode`, shouldn't your `DeleteN(root, deleteNode);` call instead be `root = DeleteN(root, deleteNode);`?

Comment: I know what you mean. But even if you delete root node the tree is fine. So i guess its no need to pass it as a reference and collect it after call. Look at part of a code with comment: "Has both child nodes". I'm using recursion call and links are rebuilded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code works. I have deleted **else** in case of **no left child** and I had only an **if statement following if statement** so it was unreachable,

```
//No child nodes
if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
{
    root = null;
    return root;
}
//No left child - DONT WORK
else if (root.left == null)  //WORKS NOW-missed else, it has been only if
{
    Node temp = root;
    root = root.right;
    temp = null;
}
//No right child
else if (root.right == null)
{
    Node temp = root;
    root = root.left;
    temp = null;
}
```