# setting reference of an object to null seems to not work

Tags: c#, .net, binary-tree

I am trying to delete a node from a binary tree using c#. This example only works if the node has no children. I understand how the deletion works with children, but I'm getting hung up on an issue that seems to me to be from a lack of understanding of c#:

```
public class Tree
{
internal class Node
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }

    public Node(int val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }
}

private Node root;
public void Delete(int val)
{
    Node current = this.root;
    Node parent = null;

    while (true) {
        if (val < current.Val) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.Left;
        }


        else if (val > current.Val) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.Right;
        }

        else if (val == current.Val) {
            current = null;
            return;
        }
    }

}

}
```

My issue is in the line where I set current = null. The way I'm intending to use this, is to use current = null to delete the current node. But it doesn't work. if I reference the current node from the parent:

```
parent.Right = null;
```

the node is properly deleted, but is obviously a pain because I need to check if the current node is the right or left child of the node. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I built something once and 'But it doesn't work.' can you help me fix it? Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715034/binary-search-tree-c-sharp-delete-node-function

Comment: This case is a perfect candidate for [ref returns and locals](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/118)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

The `current` variable is a separate variable from the `parent.Left` or `parent.Right` variables.

When you do this:

```
current = parent.Left;
```

you're copying the *value* of the variable, you're not linking one variable to another. You can liken this to postit notes. On one postit note you have an address, then you execute the above statement and copy the address onto another postit note. Changing the copy afterwards does not in any way or shape change the original note.

So yes, you need to keep track of which child reference variable you got `current` from.

Comment: To be speciffic You're not copying the value - You're makeing a copy of a reference. To prove it - if Node would have Delete() extension method and if You would call current.Delete() - it would work without tracking where the reference came from.

Comment: Well, a reference is also a value :) The value of a variable of reference type is a reference.

Comment: It's a very abstract way of thinking about values.